# Odd Perl 'dictionary' sort behaviour

Tags: perl, tcl, sorting

I'm attempting to implement the Tcl dictionary sort in Perl in order to order some files. For those who don't know Tcl, you can get it to sort continuous integers by their value, it's detailed here:

http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=160157

To summarise:
A given array of:

```
qw(
  bigbang
  x10y
  x9y
  bigboy
  bigBoy
  x11y
)
```

is sorted by case-insensitive letter, then case sensitive as a tie-breaker, then by the number, except it takes any following numbers and interprets the entire thing as a single number in the sort, so the above comes out as:

```
qw(
    bigbang
    bigBoy
    bigboy
    x9y
    x10y
    x11y
)
```

With x9y appearing above x10y and x11y, whilst in a standard ASCII sort, x10y and x11y would come above x9y, due to 1 appearing before 9.

I attempted to implement Juerd's example in that link as a function, but in my case, the sort perfectly mimics a Tcl dictionary sort when I have a list of version numbers, like the following:

```
qw{ 1 1.0 1.01 1.2 1.02 1.0003 1.102 1.103 1.203 102a 102b 103a 103b 123 };
```

But when absolute paths are used for the files, the ordering messes up.

I've posted an example script below. If anyone can see why the function is going wrong, or if you can suggest an more modern alternative (since the example I worked from was posted 10 years ago :P), I would appreciate it.

http://pastebin.com/WM6QhzSK

And if you want to see a Tcl dictionary sort in action, check the link below:

http://pastebin.com/h3qMT4C2

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:-** Thanks to `choroba` for leading me to the solution! The working function is as follows:

```
sub dict_sort {
  my @unsorted = @_;
  my @sorted =
    map $_->[0],
    sort {
      my $i = 0;
      {
        my $A = $a->[1][$i];
        my $B = $b->[1][$i];
        defined($A) || defined($B)       # Stop if both undef
        and (
          defined($A) <=> defined($B)  # Defined wins over undef
          or (
            $A !~ /\d/ || $B !~ /\d/ # $A or $B is non-integer
            ?    (lc $A cmp lc $B)   # ?? Stringy lowercase
              || (   $A cmp    $B)   #    -> Tie breaker
            : $A <=> $B              # :: $A and $B are integers
              or (
                length($A) <=> length($B)  # If numeric comparison returns the same, check length to sort by leading zeroes
              )
          )
          or ++$i && redo              # tie => next part
        );
      }
    }
  map [ $_, [ split /(\d+)/ ] ], @unsorted;
  return @sorted;
}
```

Comment: To clarify, Tcl's dictionary sorting splits each word into alternating strings of only-digits and non-digits. Digit sequences are sorted numerically (with a little magic to handle leading zeroes when two values are the same) and non-digit sequences are sorted as case-insensitive ASCII. When comparing a key which begins with digits with a key beginning with non-digits, the leading-digits one comes first.

Comment: And before anyone asks, this gives a damn good approximation to what users seem to think filenames should sort as.

Comment: Hm, it's possible that the leading zeros might be causing a problem here, but I'm surprised I don't see the same erroneous behaviour with both the version strings and the absolute paths.

Comment: And before anyone mentions anything, I personally know that the order given by a Tcl dictionary sort isn't necessarily the 'correct' one, but it's used for another piece of code I have no control over, and can't change, but have to imitate to produce the same results :)

Comment: Hint: http://p3rl.org/Sort::Naturally http://p3rl.org/Sort::Versions

Comment: Tried both of those, they don't quite work as I need them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not work differently for version strings. Just add `9.02 9.2` to the list *in this order*. If you want 02 to come after 2, you have to inspect the case when `$A == $B`.

**Update:** It means adding `or length $A <=> length $B` after the `$A <=> $B`.

Comment: So it's not changing the order because when it's comparing 1.02 and 1.2, it checks the 02 and 2, and sees them as the same when it does the $A <=> $B sort attempt?

Hm, it'd be more ideal with get it to do another check for the number of leading 0's present  when $A <=> $B returns the same, before carrying on with the rest of the sort

Comment: Thanks! I extended the search to check the length of the compared strings when the numbers match - since if one is longer than the other, but is the same value in a numeric comparison, it must have leading zeroes - and it seems to work a treat :)

I'm going to edit my code and throw in the working function, and mark yours as correct for the points. Could you edit your answer and stick my function in there to help out anybody who stumbles across similar problems?